# Why does re-seq return this vector?

Tags: regex, clojure

Given

```
(re-seq #"^([a-zA-Z\d])+:" "title: cat sat on the mat")
```

Why do I get the trailing "e" in the vector:

```
=> (["title:" "e"])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The e matches what is in the parenthesis. Any single character or digit.
Move the plus sign into the parenthesis or remove the parenthesis to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As [`re-seq` docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/re-seq) say, each match is processed by `re-groups`. You have a parenthesised expression in your regex, last of whose matches is "e" before colon.